# Windows Installation vagrant up is failing

Tags: vagrant, aerospike

Can you help me to overcome this issue?

I am trying to install Aerospike in my windows 10 (office laptop). I have downloaded latest VM Box latest vagrant.
Then through git bash, I am trying to follow the steps from aerospike windows installation, however, I am failing at 'vagrant up'. Below is the result:

```
$ vagrant up Bringing machine 'default' up with 'VirtualBox' provider...
==> default: Box 'aerospike/centos-6.5' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'aerospike/centos-6.5'
    default: URL: http / aerospike/centos-6.5
==> default: Adding box 'aerospike/centos-6.5' (v3.14.1.2) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https: //vagrantcloud.com/aerospike/boxes/centos-6.5/versions/3.14.1.2/providers/virtualbox.box
    default:

An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https: //curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
HTTPS-proxy has similar options --proxy-cacert and --proxy-insecure.

Note: I am able to load 'precise64' successfully.

Comment: which version of virtualbox are you running?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.box_download_insecure = true
```

Then re-run `vagrant up` and it should download the box

Comment: Thank you so much, the vagrant up command now worked and able to complete the job. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Issue seems to be openssl related.

Please see the following:

http://slick.pl/kb/software/vagrant-fix-for-error-60-ssl-read/

The workaround is to  have vagrant download it in an unsecure way:

```
vagrant box add --insecure -c aerospike/centos-6.5 https://vagrantcloud.com/aerospike/boxes/centos-6.5/versions/3.14.1.2/providers/virtualbox.box

vagrant init aerospike/centos-6.5

vagrant up
```